# How to Install Tomcat 6.0 without MSI installer

Tags: apache, tomcat6

I want to Install Tomcat Apache 6.0 in Windows 7. When I download from the site in the zip format and extracted as folder.

[image]
[image]

Query:
How to install tomcat apache server from this folder, Since it doesn't have MSI installer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install and you can startup Tomcat by `bin/startup.bat`.